# Which action(s) can I use to create a folder in SharePoint Online via Azure Logic App?

Tags: azure, sharepoint-online, azure-logic-apps

As question title states, I am looking for a proper action in Logic Apps to create a folder. This action will be executed several times -- once per directory as per business rule. There will be no files created in these folders because the intent of the Logic App is to prepare a template folder structure for the users' needs.

In the official documentation I see that there are [create file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#Create_file), [create item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#Create_item), and [list folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#List_folder) actions. They suggest that there *might* be an action to create a folder too (which I can't find).

If such action does not exist, I may need to use some SharePoint Online API, but that will be a last resort solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to create a directory by means of [SharePoint - CreateFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#Create_file) action. Creating a directory via a side effect of the file creation action is definitely a dirty hack (btw, inspired by [a comment on MS suggestion site](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/18512320-sharepoint-create-folder)). This bug/feature is not documented, so relying on it in production environment is probably not a good idea.

More that that, if my problem requires creating a directory in SharePoint without any files in it whatsoever, an extra step in App Logic needs to be used. Make sure to delete the file using the `Id` provided by `Create File` action.

Here's what your JSON might look like, if you were trying to create a directory called `folderCreatedAsSideEffect` under **preexisting** `TestTarget` document library.

```
"actions": {
    "Create_file": {
        "inputs": {
            "body": "@triggerBody()?['Name']",
            "host": { "connection": { "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sharepointonline']['connectionId']" } },
            "method": "post",
            "path": "/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('https://MY.sharepoint.com/LogicApps/'))}/files",
            "queries": {
                "folderPath": "/TestTarget/folderCreatedAsSideEffect",
                "name": "placeholder"
            }
        },
        "runAfter": {},
        "type": "ApiConnection"
    },
    "Delete_file": {
        "inputs": {
            "host": { "connection": { "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sharepointonline']['connectionId']" } },
            "method": "delete",
            "path": "/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('https://MY.sharepoint/LogicApps/'))}/files/@{encodeURIComponent(body('Create_file')?['Id'])}"
        },
        "runAfter": {
            "Create_file": [
                "Succeeded"
            ]
        },
        "type": "ApiConnection"
    }
},
```

[image: ...]

Comment: This describes the REST API i could use instead. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/rest/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest

Answer (score 1):

Correct, so far the SharePoint Connector does not support Folder management tasks.

So, your best option currently is to use the SharePoint API or client libraries in an API or Function App.

Comment: Would it be possible to use `CreateFile` operation that targets a non-existing folder to create a folder as a side effect? Or will it such operation fail due to the absence of the targeted folder? I know it's cheap and dirty, yet still simpler than to deal with API I think.

Comment: I posted a dirty hack based solution if you're interested. This uses a wrong action of the SharePoint native connector. At the point where my project is (prototyping stage), it's sufficient and simple solution I can afford to use. Not great for production though.

Comment: I am hesitant to accept my hacky answer. If you have an example for the SharePoint API based solution, it would be a big plus and definitely make your answer the "righter" one.