# Creating a SharePoint folder using Logic Apps

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, azure-logic-apps

I was using the following SO post to create a folder in a SharePoint list: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47665622/which-actions-can-i-use-to-create-a-folder-in-sharepoint-online-via-azure-logi)

It kinda-sorta works, but not as expected. Here is the way the logic works:

1. A Policy is either new or has been updated in our Document Library,
   which acts as my trigger for Logic Apps
2. The condition then looks forthe word "Policy" in the File Identifier
3. It then goes and creates a folder in another SharePoint list (Policy Acknowledgement), based on the filename/Policy Name
4. Then it sends an email to staff advising them that a new/updated policy is available to read, which then has another link that says "I agree, etc"
5. This then writes to the Policy Acknowledgement list that the user has read the document

So all steps seem to work, except for when I go to view the Policy Acknowledgement list, the new folder created for that Policy doesn't display in the list. However, if I type in the address to the list/folder, I can view it. Here are my steps, below:

1. [Create the folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Y7N2.jpg)
2. [Send the email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8C0I.jpg)
3. [Acknowledge the Policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4rsz.jpg)
4. [List where the new folder should be created - But doesn't](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MibfQ.jpg)
    (the other 3 folders were manually created for testing purposes)
5. [Here is the actual folder, once the direct URL is typed-in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YIfk.jpg)
6. [Although the folder isn't listed in SP, it still appears in Logic Apps as an actual folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSwP2.jpg)

This isn't an issue for me, as I can always type in the address manually to get to the Policy Folder. But this is meant to be for our HR team, who just want to be able to open the "Policy Acknowledgement" list, and view all the Policy Folders in there.

I am starting to look down the path of creating a PowerShell runbook, that creates the folder for me, if that is the last resort (or should it have been my first resort?).